# aggregate group multiple result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I try to aggregate operation '$group' ..
I want to get multiple group result.

My data is this..

```
items: [
  {
   director: "James",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "apple",
   money: 5000
  },
  {
   director: "James",
   category: "toy",
   name: "dragon",
   money: 15000
  },
  {
   director: "Sam",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "orange",
   money: 3500
  }
]
```

I want to get result, This !!

```
directorList:[
  {
   director: "James",
   money: 20000
  },
  {
   director: "Sam",
   money: 3500
  }
],
categoryList: [
  {
   category: "fruit",
   money: 8500
  },
  {
   category: "toy",
   money: 15000
  }
]
```

Answer please..
Thanks..!!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: $unwind, $group, and $group, $project ..... and $unwind, $group, $group .....
I don't know $facet operation. this is wonderful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "directorList": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$director",
        "money": { "$sum": "$money" }
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "_id": false,
        "director": "$_id",
        "money": 1
      }}
    ],
    "categoryList": [
      { "$group:" {
        "_id": "$category",
        "money": { "$sum": "$money" }
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "_id": false,
        "category": "$_id",
        "money": 1
      }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "categoryList": [
      {
        "category": "toy",
        "money": 15000
      },
      {
        "category": "fruit",
        "money": 8500
      }
    ],
    "directorList": [
      {
        "director": "Sam",
        "money": 3500
      },
      {
        "director": "James",
        "money": 20000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5QUXrEimkPH)

Comment: Wow ! Thank you. I'm pleasure your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm blocked another problem ..

```
items: [
  {
   mart_code : 1,
   director: "James",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "apple",
   money: 5000
  },
  {
   mart_code: 1
   director: "James",
   category: "toy",
   name: "dragon",
   money: 15000
  },
  {
   mart_code: 2,
   director: "Sam",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "orange",
   money: 3500
  }
]
```

I want to get result..
mart_code is added ..

```
martList: [ {
  mart_code: 1,
  directorList:[
  {
   director: "James",
   money: 20000
  }
  ],
  categoryList: [
  {
   category: "fruit",
   money: 5000
  },
  {
   category: "toy",
   money: 15000
  }] 
},
{
  mart_code: 2,
  directorList:[
  {
   director: "Sam",
   money: 3500
  }
  ],
  categoryList: [
  {
   category: "fruit",
   money: 3500
  }]
}
]
```

I trying to $facet, and $group, $project...
Is there an efficient way?